# QCalendarWidget - How to disable dates

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QCalendarWidget with enabled or disabled dates (and not only range dates) but it's look impossible (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-198).

Do you know if it is possible to do this with paintEvent method (or something else) ?

Thank's for reading :)

Answer (score 3):

I've done some research. The calendar widget contains a regular `QTableView` subclass (`QCalendarView`) with a regular model (`QCalendarModel`). My attempt was to add a proxy model for the view and change `data()` and `flags()` functions to return disabled state for the dates I wanted to disable. But I needed to know which date is displayed on a cell. There is `QCalendarModel::dateForCell` method for that, but it's inaccessible from the code. It's rather complicated and depends on implementation of `QCalendarModel`.

So I think that this is hardly possible. The only way I see is to copy `QCalendarWidget` source to your project and rename classes to avoid conflicts along existing Qt classes. Then you can change implementation. In any place where minimum and maximum date is used (e.g. in `QCalendarModel::flags` function) you should replace it with use of your enabled/disabled class list.

In case you find something useful in my attempt, I've published the code [here](https://gist.github.com/Riateche/6069399). The proxy model is incepted and all cells' background is made green.

Comment: Lot of thank's for your answer, sorry for my late reply. I'll try your solution next week and examinate your source code.